# How to pull repo from composer.json in a jenkins job

Tags: php, jenkins, composer-php

I am trying to run `composer install` in the command shell section of jenkins, but when I build the job, its failing because `composer.json` contains a repository section.

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "git@gitlab*****"
    }
],
```

in jenkin's **Source Code Management** I did added the git credentials plus the repository URL (this is working fine and building fine) this is a different repo than the one in the **composer.json**.

The only problem is that I cant pull the git repo inside the composer.json file (giving permission denied), my thinking is that jenkins doesnt store the ssh keys, it only execute when its building and then remove, am i right to think this? and if so how can I overcome this? And if not what am I doing wrong, how can i avoid having permission denied when pulling git repos inside a composer.json?

Comment: Have you tried running the command as the jenkins user, i.e. using `sudo -u jenkins composer install` to see if you have the same problem? Most likely you have to provide a gitlab-token to composer to gain access to the repository. Alternatively you could create an ssh key pair on your jenkins and then add the public key to the repository to allow access.